# 301 Redirects in Next.js without passing the query from source URL to destination URL

Tags: redirect, nextjs, next.js, next

1. Есть source-URL вида `https://example.com/category/results/refine?dealers=123&inv=true&sellertypes=dealer`
2. Хочется перманентно (301) редиректить этот source-URL на destination-URL вида `https://example.com/` при условии если source-URL в query содержит ключи `dealers` (любые) и `inv` (в значении true).
3. В соответствии с документацией Next.js реализовал следующее в  `next.config.ts`:

   ```
   async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/category/results/refine",
        has: [
          {
            type: "query",
            key: "dealers",
          },
          {
            type: "query",
            key: "inv",
            value: "true",
          },
        ],
        destination: "/",
        permanent: true,
        statusCode: 301,
      },
    }
   ```
4. Но вместо редиректа на `https://example.com/` получаю редирект на `https://example.com/?dealers=123&inv=true&sellertypes=dealer`. То есть query из source-URL приклеивается к destination-URL, а мне надо чтобы последний был без query.

Comment: Слава, это российский сегмент. Или по-русски, или в ангилийский сегмент этот вопрос.

Comment: Сергей, спасибо!